# Add disable to div class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to add and remove class `disabled` on button click.
I tried to add it using but `var r` is not assigned correctly to the div.

```
var r = $("div.radio.ui-buttonset");
        alert(r)
        if(r) {
            r.className += r.className ? ' disabled' : 'disabled';
        }
```

HTML

```
<div class="input radio optional ui-buttonset">
   radio buttons
</div>
```

Desired HTML result on click:

```
<div class="input radio optional ui-buttonset disabled">
   radio buttons
</div>
```

Desired HTML result another click: (back to original)

```
<div class="input radio optional ui-buttonset">
   radio buttons
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('div.radio.ui-buttonset').toggleClass('disabled');
```

Good luck!

Comment: I think I am missing something in the selector. Because I am not getting the div.

Comment: It's unclear from the code you submitted since it looks correct.

Comment: `$("div.radio.ui-buttonset")` is this selector correct for `<div class="input radio optional ui-buttonset">` ??

Comment: Yes it is. Are you sure the div exists in the rendered html? Are you using anything that generates the div that has not been triggered yet?

Comment: No. It's working but its adding disabled to other classes as well. Sorry. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery, just use ".removeClass()":

```
r.removeClass("disabled");
```

To add the class back, there's ".addClass()":

```
r.addClass("disabled");
```

*edit* — Given the markup you posted, the selector you're using to get the target `<div>` element should work fine. It's looking for a `<div>` that's got the two classes "radio" and "ui-buttonset", and according to the HTML you posted that's correct. If it's not working, you need to describe how exactly it's not working.

Comment: but first I have to get r. I am not able to get the correct div using  `var r = $("div.radio.ui-buttonset");`

Comment: It would have been helpful if you had mentioned that problem in your question.